# Restrict product quantity drop down value

Tags: magento-1.9

In all my product have 100 inventory, i want to display drop down in view page. I used below mention code

```
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity') ?></label>
    <select class="input-text qty" name="qty" id="qty">
<?php $i = 1 ?>
<?php do { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $i?>">
<?php echo $i?>
<?php $i++ ?>
</option>
<?php } while ($i <= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()) ?>
</select>
```

But problem is it showing all 100 i need only 10 product in that drop down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good practise to calculate the product qty in each loop iteration.

Better query the qty for the product once:

```
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity') ?></label>
<select class="input-text qty" name="qty" id="qty">
  <?php $i = 1 ?>
  <?php $productQty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>
  <?php do { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $i?>">
    <?php echo $i?>
    <?php $i++ ?>
    </option>
<?php } while ($i <= $productQty && $i <= 10) ?>
</select>
```

See also "[Conquer the 5 Most Common Magento Coding Issues to Optimize Your Site for Performance](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/conquer_the_5_most_common_magento_coding_issues_to_optimize_your_site_for_performance.pdf)" on page 7 for more information about how to avoid loading models in a loop.

Comment: @Anna That is correct, I edited my answer again. thanks for sharing this nice information.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below

```
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity') ?></label>
    <select class="input-text qty" name="qty" id="qty">

        <?php $i = 1 ?>
        <?php $productQty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>
        <?php do { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i ?>">
                <?php echo $i ?>
                <?php $i++ ?>
            </option>
            <?php if ($i == 11) {
                break;
            } ?>
    <?php } while ($i <= $productQty) ?></select>
```

Comment: Great, you can accept this answer if that work for you :)

Comment: i can't able to accept immediately after 5 min only answer will be accepted so plz wait